# How to turn off UINavigationTransitionView's clipToBounds value?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

`UITableView` placed in `UINavigationController` will have a parent view with type `UINavigationTransitionView`, and its `clipToBounds` is `true`, though I need it to `false`. How can I set it? From code? Is it not possible with Storyboard?

Is it a way to get reference to `UINavigationTransitionView` from `UINavigationController`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
self.navigationController?.view.subviews[0].clipsToBounds = false
```